# Laravel Simple jquery request and return not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Here is my Script

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register', 'class' => 'form-signin')) }}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.post("back",{ name: "Zara" },function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }
          );
      });
   });
   </script>
   <div id="stage">
        STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('back', function()
{
    return View::make('back');
});
```

And the view has : a simple echo

```
 <?php
 if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

When i press the submit i got the following error in the console

```
error: {type:Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException, message:,…}
file: "D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MySample\bootstrap\compiled.php"
line: 5704
message: ""
type: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
```

What is the mistake i am doing ?

Comment: you are defining route to response to get request, but in jquery, you send post request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your Route from

```
Route::get('back', function()
```

to

```
Route::post('back', function()
```

Comment: Thanks, i missed that simple logic :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("back",{ name: "Zara" },function(data) {
     $('#stage').html(data);
   }
);
```

Should match a POST route, not a GET one:

```
Route::post('back', function() {}
```

Either you change jQuery with `$.get(...)` or your route